Why is my MUI X Line chart only showing the last value when hovering on any of the charts marker points
I'm utilizing MUI x charts to display data visually. The chart visualization itself is functioning correctly. However, I'm encountering an issue where only the latest marker point is being displayed when hovering.

Does anyone know why the data is showed perfect but only the latest line is selected when hovering?
I have create an example below:
MUI x chart example

You need to the reverse order of data array like this:
data: [// your items].reverse()
CodeSandbox
For some reason, it is expecting the datetime in decreasing order.

This does the trick indeed! Thank you, I'll reward the bounty as soon as Stackoverflow alows me to.
